# Pip Proxy error when installing packages

Tags: python, proxy, pip, anaconda

I am using the anaconda3 distribution of Python that comes with most packages. I tried to install the `teradata` module using:

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port teradata
```

but im getting a `407 proxy connection error`.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Can you please put the full error message?

Comment: Error message: after a connection broken by proxyError('cannot connect to proxy.',newConnectionError('<pip._vendor.request.packages.urllib3.connection.verifiedHTTPSComnection at x000000000003F...>:Failed to establish a new connection:[Errorno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))':/simple/teradata/

Comment: @Alberto Garcia-Raboso does that look familiar ?